# Why is this negated with nicht and not kein?

Tags: negation

A text I am studying has the following sentence,

> Eine freie Presse gab es nicht.

This contradicts everything I thought I understood about creating negative sentences in German. Surely the correct way to put this sentence is

> Es gab keine freie Presse.

Comment: Compare English: *There was no free press* / *A free press did not exist*.

Comment: @RHa Or for slightly more purple-prose effect: "A free press it was not!"

Answer (score 35):

A *nicht* at the end of a clause means the verb in second position is negated. So, in

> Eine freie Presse **gab** es **nicht**.

the predicate is *nicht geben*. That's slightly different from

> Es gab **keine freie Presse**.

where *eine freie Presse* is negated.

In your example, there is little semantic difference. The reason why the first form was used is the special position in front of the clause. **It's the topic.** The alternative

> Keine freie Presse gab es.

which has the negated *freie Presse* as the topic sounds off. There's even a pun  using that for effect:

> In a former GDR *Kaufhaus*:
>
> Haben Sie denn keine Schuhe? — Hier gibt's keine Hosen. Keine Schuhe gibt's dahinten.

Comment: Einer meiner liebsten Witze! :)

Comment: Good analysis of "negated verb" vs. "negated object". One difference between the two is that you can have a mix of negated and unnegated objects with the same verb: "Es gab Hosen, Pullover, aber *keine* Schuhe."

Comment: It's been too long since I was around German people.  I love that joke!

Answer (score 14):

Both sentences are right. It's a matter of emphasis. If you hear a sentence starting with

> Eine freie Presse ...

your expectation is: Ah, we are talking about freedom of speech now. What about free press? Well

> ... gab es nicht.

Oh. That's bad. If the sentence starts with

> Es gab keine ...

then it's more about *was es gab* and *was es nicht gab*.

I guess you already know that word order in German is pretty free. Different word order is almost always about emphasis.

Answer (score 4):

Put simply, it's this: *nicht* means the verb doesn't.  *kein* means the noun isn't.  So both those sample sentences are correct -- either the free press *does not exist,* or *there isn't a free press.*

Comment: That is a remarkably useful and appreciated insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in the sentence

> Eine freie Presse **gab** es **nicht**.

The "nicht" negates the Verb "gab" besically claiming **nonexistence**. While

> Es gab **keine** freie **Presse**.

uses "keine" to count the amount of "Pressen" and therfore claiming the **existence of none**.

In practice those are one and the same, you simply need to remember that "kein/keine/etc." are counting the noun associated. While "nicht" is basically saying "this sentence without **nicht** is wrong".

Answer (score -2):

As far as I remember you use *kein(e)* when the subject of negation has no article (definite or indefinite), just like in your example.

Verbs are a perfect example of such use cases.

Answer (score -5):

it's not just about word order. *nicht* and *kein* are different words. *gab es* is a kind of impassive, middle voice (whatever) and this allows for very different interpretations of "es" and the focus of the negative polarity item. If press is in subject position, it must exist in principle and can't be negated later; that's why a proxy, the indefinite pronoun *es* has to be used in an alternate construction.

In practice there is not always a notable difference, if the constructions are freely interpreted. @Janka's explanation is on point for the general difference between *nicht* and *keine*.

I'd say either:

> the free press if there was any wasn't given any room;
>
> the room if there was any didn't bear the free press

of course this shifts the problem to one about the metaphorical Freiräume, Schutzräume, etc. and the agentless passive "wasn't given".